# Were any mammals born in space (or are there any confirmed planned missions to breed them)?

Tags: iss, life, research, animals

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5345/33950) claims rats had been born in space, but link with confirmation is broken.

[Some pregnant rats](http://www.indiana.edu/~rcapub/v27n1/rats.shtml) were in space, but those didn't give birth in space.

[This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4513/33950) has good answers regarding reproduction of various animals in space, but not mammals.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21857/33950) contains link describing some plans back in 2016 to breed mice and small rabits in ISS/Kibo facility.

So, are there any fresh updates on the question "Were any mammals born in space"? If not, are there any confirmed planned missions in the nearest future to breed mammals in space?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20151026124623/http://www.aticourses.com/blog/index.php/tag/document-12-571-3570/

Comment: @Sneftel that link doesn't explicitly mention *a birth* in space and lacks references regarding used wording "*developed*".

Comment: Yes, I know. It's the first link you were trying to access.

Comment: @LeoS I found the source for the study that link refers to. The rats were not born in space. They were fetal rats that were taken up and raised in microgravity: https://web.archive.org/web/20110809060317/http://gateway.nlm.nih.gov/MeetingAbstracts/ma?f=102222743.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly if a mammal would have given birth in zero gravity, it would have been mice, rats, or other similar rodents. I have found a few studies which had mice that were pregnant at launch, made it to space, and returned home before they came to term and gave birth back on Earth, with no problems being observed. A [number of experiments](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/space-babies-study-suggests-human-may-be-able-to-have-healthy-offspring-in-orbit-a7750701.html) have been done with a large variety of tests, but to date, no births have happened in zero gravity, nor natural conception (IVF has been done, however)

So far as I can tell, all experiments done have been to either subject pregnant mice to a few days of space travel in the middle of their pregnancy, bringing samples of sperm/ ovaries to space and seeing if they are still vital after, or I believe one instance of IVF (Although that might have been related to the previous). The article I linked to had a date of 2017.

I'm fairly sure that when this happens, it will be pretty widely known, like Dolly the cloned sheep.

Comment: Now that I have ruled out the alleged births referred to in dotancohen's answer, I can firmly agree with you that there have been no mammalian births in space.